# How to start node server in aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, bitnami

Can anybody help me to start node server in aws, my application is under mean stack, Project directory on ubuntu linux is as followos:

/home/bitnami/projects/website

and dist folder is also inside the website folder,

When i place the public ip for my website i am getting message

**You are now running Bitnami MEAN 4.2.2-0 in the Cloud.**

after googling this is come to my knowledge i need to stop default server and start the node server for my app,
Any quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You will basically need to configure a ProxyPass in Apache to serve app's information when accessing to the IP/domain of the instance.

```
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Those lines can be added in the main virtual host file (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf) or in the app-specific configuration files (/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf). You will need to restart Apache later

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You can find more information about this in [our documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/mean/administration/create-custom-application-nodejs/) or in [this other Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62039295/4709625)

Comment: Remember to also enable `mod_proxy` for this.